# php script permission denied on server while creating file dynamically

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

I'm stuck on letting php create files on my server from the html forms output. It doesn't have permission to create these files. I tried different approaches I around here but can't get it to work.

Here's my code which creates the file from the Form data:

```
$file = 'r-data/car-form-data-'.time().'-'.rand(1000,9999).'.JSON';
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($_POST));
```

Is somebody able to help to make this approach work?

Thank you.

Comment: You are using an absolute path and the web-server user does not have - and should not have - write permissions on the root of the filesystem. You should write your files in a specific sub-directory and give the web-user (apache / www / etc.) permissions to write there.

Comment: That fixed it, forgot to put the sub dir in. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe www-data doesn't have right to write on your folder.
Try `chmod -R 777` on your folder or set acl.